# How to apply Linest function in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I trying to get a third order LinEst function in VBA. However, the error always come out as Expected array when it reaches Ubound(xl).

```
Option Explicit
Sub RB()

Dim xl As Range, e As Double
Dim yl As Range, s As Variant
Dim X



With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set yl = .Range(.Cells(17, 7), .Cells(93, 7))

Set xl = .Range(.Cells(17, 1), .Cells(93, 1))

ReDim arrX3(1 To UBound(xl), 1 To 3) As Double
For i = LBound(xl) To UBound(xl)
arrX2(i, 1) = xl(i, 1)
arrX2(i, 2) = xl(i, 1) * xl(i, 1)
arrX2(i, 3) = xl(i, 1) * xl(i, 1) * xl(i, 1)
Next

X = Application.LinEst(yl, arrX3)
.Range(.Cells(12, 12), .Cells(15, 14)).Value = Application.Transpose(X)

End With    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xl` is a Range and **not** an array. So, `Ubound(xl)` won't work. While I do not understand what you're code is trying to achieve, I believe that you are looking for something along the line like this:

```
Option Base 1
Option Explicit

Sub RB()

Dim xl As Range, e As Double
Dim yl As Range, s As Variant
Dim X As Variant, i As Long

e = 76

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set yl = .Range(.Cells(17, 7), .Cells(e - 1, 7))
    Set xl = .Range(.Cells(17, 1), .Cells(e - 1, 1))

    Debug.Print "First row in xl is " & xl.Row
    Debug.Print "Range xl has " & xl.Rows.Count & " rows"
    Debug.Print "Last row in xl is " & xl.Rows.Count + xl.Row - 1


    ReDim arrX3(1 To xl.Rows.Count, 1 To 3) As Double
    For i = 1 To xl.Rows.Count
        arrX3(i, 1) = xl.Cells(i, 1)
        arrX3(i, 2) = xl.Cells(i, 1) * xl.Cells(i, 1)
        arrX3(i, 3) = xl.Cells(i, 1) * xl.Cells(i, 1) * xl.Cells(i, 1)
    Next i

    X = Application.LinEst(yl, arrX3)
    .Range(.Cells(12, 12), .Cells(15, 14)).Value = Application.Transpose(X)

End With

End Sub
```

Note, that I added a few `Debug.Print` which you might want to have a look at.

Answer (score 0):

`xl` is declared to be a range and ranges don't have a `Ubound`.

Change the declaration of `xl` from `Range` to `Variant` and replace the line

```
Set xl = .Range(.Cells(17, 1), .Cells(93, 1))
```

by

```
xl = .Range(.Cells(17, 1), .Cells(93, 1)).Value
```

I'm not sure if this will be enough to make your code run as expected, but it will at least get rid of the error that you describe.